# angular manage data of multiple http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, get

I have a serious problem in this case.
I am getting data from github API by this code below but since github alllow only 30 results per page I would like to fetch all data for better sort options and push it to one array of objects. Below find a code
this one works fine

```
$scope.getData = function () {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: api url + pageNum
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.mydata = response.data;
            $scope.isLoading = false;
            $scope.result = $scope.mydata.map(function (a) { return { 'name': a.name, 'html_url': a.html_url }; });

        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.error = response.statusText;

        });
    };
```

But I would like to do something like this

```
$scope.getData = function () {
for(var i =0; i<= $scope.pages.length; i++){
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "apiUrl + i
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.mydata = response.data;
            $scope.isLoading = false;
            $scope.result = $scope.mydata.map(function (a) { return { 'name': a.name, 'html_url': a.html_url }; });

        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.error = response.statusText;

        });
    };
```

Any ideas hw to do this ?

Comment: I've done something similar at work using a $q.all() to resolve all promises. Unfortunately, I can't access the repos now, nor do I have the necessary setup at home to try an example. Try looking in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [$q documentation in the AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
$scope.getData = function () {
    $scope.result = [];
    $scope.error = [];
    $q.all($scope.pages.map(function(page) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "apiUrl" + i
        })
        // This function will be triggered when each call is finished.
        .then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.mydata.push(response.data);
            $scope.result.push($scope.mydata.map(function (a) { return { 'name': a.name, 'html_url': a.html_url }; }));

        })
    }))
    // This call will be called when all of the calls are finished.
    .then(function(success) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.error = response.statusText;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You, gonna check it out. I ll let You know